# apache mod_rewrite non-existing file to something

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i have rule like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/show_video.php?id=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/(.*)$ /video/$1 [R]
</IfModule>
```

i want to redirect: http://www.domain.com/show_video.php?id=8
to
http://www.domain.com/video/8/

show_video.php does not exist on the server.

how do i do that? my rule does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the `QUERY_STRING` in a rewrite condition, here is an example that probably would work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^show_video\.php$ /video/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to match against the query string using a `RewriteCond` and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable, then use the `%1` to backreference the match:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?show_video.php$ /video/%1/? [R,L]
```